# Ajax post request is working fine but in console it shows " POST http://controller/action 500 (Internal Server Error) "

Tags: c#, ajax, json, asp.net-mvc

In Network Tab it shows:

> The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection.

This is my logic class where there is a method which insert data received from controller.

```
public static object AddContestant(string mode,int contestantid,string firstname,string lastname,DateTime dob,bool active,int district,string gender,string address)
{
    using(ContestantDBEntities db = new ContestantDBEntities())
    {
        if (mode == "InsertMode")
        {
            Contestant insert = new Contestant();

            insert.Firstname = firstname;
            insert.Lastname = lastname;

            db.Contestants.Add(insert);
            db.SaveChanges();

            var obj = db.Contestants.ToList();
            return obj;
        }
        else if (mode == "EditMode")
        {
            var edit = db.Contestants.Where(x => x.Id == contestantid).FirstOrDefault();

            edit.Firstname = firstname;
            edit.Lastname = lastname;

            db.SaveChanges();

            var obj = db.Contestants.ToList();
            return obj;
        }
        else 
        {
            var obj = db.Contestants.ToList();
            return obj;
        }
    }
}
```

This is my Controller.

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult AddContestant(string mode,string firstname,string lastname)
{
    var obj = ContestantManager.AddContestant(mode,firstname,lastname);
    return Json(obj,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

This is my View.

```
    <div class="row"><br />
               <div class="col-md-4"> <label>First Name</label> </div> 
               <div class="col-md-6"> <input  class="form-control" type="text" id="txtFirstName" /></div>
          </div>
         <div class="row"><br />
               <div class="col-md-4"> <label>Last Name</label> </div> 
               <div class="col-md-6"> <input  class="form-control" type="text" id="txtLastName" /></div>
         </div>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="btnSaveContestant">Save Contestant</button>
<script>
(document.body).on('click', '#btnSaveContestant', function () {
    var mode = $('#txtmode').val(); 
    var firstname = $('#txtFirstName').val();
    var lastname = $('#txtLastName').val();

    var alldata = {
        'mode': mode,
        'firstname': firstname,
        'lastname': lastname,
    };
    $.ajax({
        //dataType:"json",
        type: "POST",
        url: "Contestant/AddContestant",
        data: alldata,
    })
    .success(function (obj)
    {
        alert("success");
        console.log(obj);
    })
    .error(function (obj)
    {
        alert('error');
    })
});
</script>
```

I don't know the reason why my controller return object is disposed and ajax success method is not receiving any JSON object although controller action is inserting data and returning JSON object.

Comment: Please add the code for `Contestant` to your question.

Comment: Does `Contestant` have navigation properties and do you use lazy loading?

Comment: lazy loading is false in my dbcontext

Comment: hey CodeCaster i already go through above link. but in my case it does not work. There must be another reason why my ajax success method is not receiving json object.

Comment: Helo everybody may be my problem is same but solution may be different..i tried every thing but nothing works. i also go through above question which claimed as duplicate and go through answer but those answer doesnot solve my problem..Come on there must be another solution..i search a lot believe me..help me